# Change logo image For CASino, a Ruby Single Sign-on solution

Tags: ruby, sass

According to use CASino Single Sign-On solution i'm editing the logo like it says here with the scss file:

http://casino.rbcas.com/docs/customization/

I add the image and change the path, for example:

```
$logo: "any_image.png";
```

then don't shows anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved!**

*The logo is used as background, cause you must **edit** the **image size** properties*.